# What is a straightforward way to parse hierarchical namespaces for filenames in Azure Storage Uri's using KQL?

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I'm trying to create a Log Analytics Workbook for some Azure Blob Storage accounts. The accounts are ADLS Gen2 w/ Hierarchical Namespaces enabled. The issue is that *some* files are uploaded directly under the *Container-level*, some are uploaded inside subdirectories or subsubdirectories (Hierarchical Namespaces).

This makes it rather challenging to surface filenames using KQL.

Is there a simple way to grab each subdirectory if they exist and each filename or do I have to come up with a custom method for each blob container?

**Example:**

```
// Define variables
let varStartTime            = todatetime('2022-10-02T18:00:00Z');
let varEndTime              = todatetime('2022-10-02T20:00:00Z');
let varAccountName          = 'stgtest';
//
StorageBlobLogs
| where
    AccountName == varAccountName
    and TimeGenerated       between (varStartTime .. varEndTime)
| extend FileName           = todynamic(split(Uri, '/')) // herein lies the issue
| project
    TimeGenerated,
    AccountName,
    OperationName,
    FileName
| sort by TimeGenerated asc
```

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: HNS has nothing to do with your scenario.  Paths in object storage look the same as Paths in HNS. It's the implementation behind the scenes that is different. Please share some samples + required results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[parse_url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseurlfunction)
[parse_path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parsepathfunction)

```
StorageBlobLogs
| sample 15
| project Uri
| extend Path = parse_path(tostring(parse_url(Uri).Path))
| evaluate bag_unpack(Path, "Path_")
```

[Azure Log Analytics | Demo Environment](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_Monitoring_Logs/DemoLogsBlade)

[image: Results]